# how to use a base class in dplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, base-class

I'm trying to use the [RQuantLib](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQuantLib/RQuantLib.pdf) package to calculate the implied volatility of options in a dataframe using the function EuropeanImpliedVolatility. The function returns a base class and get the error `Expecting a single string value: [type=integer; extent=1]`.

What is the correct method to use a base class in dplyr?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RQuantLib)

    book <- data.frame(
      type=c("call","call","call","put","put","put"),
      strike=c(27800,27600,27400,24800,24600,24400),
      last=c(240,280,320,310,270,230),
      underlying=rep(26425,6),
      dividendYield=rep(0,6),
      riskFreeRate=rep(0.015,6),
      maturity=rep(39/365,6)
    ) %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(
        impvol= EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(type, value=last, underlying,strike,dividendYield,riskFreeRate,maturity,volatility=0.4)
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some attributes, which cause the issue.  We could wrap with `as.numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(RQuantLib)
book %>%
   rowwise %>%
    mutate(impvol = as.numeric(EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(type, 
        value=last, underlying, strike,
                dividendYield,riskFreeRate,maturity,volatility = 0.4)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Rowwise: 
#  type  strike  last underlying dividendYield riskFreeRate maturity impvol
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 call   27800   240      26425             0        0.015    0.107  0.204
#2 call   27600   280      26425             0        0.015    0.107  0.202
#3 call   27400   320      26425             0        0.015    0.107  0.197
#4 put    24800   310      26425             0        0.015    0.107  0.275
#5 put    24600   270      26425             0        0.015    0.107  0.277
#6 put    24400   230      26425             0        0.015    0.107  0.278
```

---

or wrap in a `list`, if we want to keep the attributes as such

```
book %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(impvol = list(EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(type, 
    value=last, underlying,strike,dividendYield,
            riskFreeRate,maturity,volatility=0.4)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Rowwise: 
#  type  strike  last underlying dividendYield riskFreeRate maturity impvol        
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl> <list>        
#1 call   27800   240      26425             0        0.015    0.107 <ErpnOpIV [1]>
#2 call   27600   280      26425             0        0.015    0.107 <ErpnOpIV [1]>
#3 call   27400   320      26425             0        0.015    0.107 <ErpnOpIV [1]>
#4 put    24800   310      26425             0        0.015    0.107 <ErpnOpIV [1]>
#5 put    24600   270      26425             0        0.015    0.107 <ErpnOpIV [1]>
#6 put    24400   230      26425             0        0.015    0.107 <ErpnOpIV [1]>
```

---

Or another option with `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
book %>%
    mutate(impvol = pmap_dbl(., ~ EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(..1, value = ..3,
           ..4, ..2, ..5, ..6, ..7, volatility = 0.4)))
#  type strike last underlying dividendYield riskFreeRate  maturity    impvol
#1 call  27800  240      26425             0        0.015 0.1068493 0.2044270
#2 call  27600  280      26425             0        0.015 0.1068493 0.2019167
#3 call  27400  320      26425             0        0.015 0.1068493 0.1973822
#4  put  24800  310      26425             0        0.015 0.1068493 0.2745614
#5  put  24600  270      26425             0        0.015 0.1068493 0.2773029
#6  put  24400  230      26425             0        0.015 0.1068493 0.2780447
```

#### data

```
book <- data.frame(
      type=c("call","call","call","put","put","put"),
      strike=c(27800,27600,27400,24800,24600,24400),
      last=c(240,280,320,310,270,230),
      underlying=rep(26425,6),
      dividendYield=rep(0,6),
      riskFreeRate=rep(0.015,6),
      maturity=rep(39/365,6)
    )
```

Comment: @Zeus Can you show the package version of `dplyr`.  Both the methods are working fine for me

Comment: I think you're right - I'm using dplyr 1.0.2

Comment: @Zeus I am also using `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.2’`  May be you have some package masking function issue?  Can you try on a fresh session with only `dplyr` and `RQuantLib` loaded

Comment: i tried the code in a new session but get the same error

Comment: @Zeus Do you get the error with `pmap` as well

Comment: @Zeus As we have the same `dplyr` version, may be it is 'RQuantLib' version issue i.e. I have `packageVersion("RQuantLib")#
[1] ‘0.4.12’`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226264/discussion-between-zeus-and-akrun).

Comment: thanks for your help - all methods work, the issue was outdated R code which had other functions